# Update IPython namespace when running script from command-line

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, ipython-magic

In Ipython 0.10, it was possible to run a script from the command-line, then from the interactive mode, immediately get access to the names in the namespace:

```
ipython -i some_script.py

%whos
    tom
    dick
    jane
```

I'm now using Python 3.3.2 and IPython 1.1.0.  Somewhere along the line, this behavior changed.  Now I get:

```
ipython3 -i some_script.py

%whos
    Interactive namespace empty
```

I now must start IPython, then %run the script to have the namespace preserved:

```
ipython3 -i
%run some_script.py
%whos
    tom
    dick
    jane
```

Is there a command-line option or technique that will give me the old behavior?  I've tried

```
ipython3 -i -c "%run some_script.py"
```

but that doesn't work either.

I know, it's a lazy thing, but having one less step speeds up debugging spins.

Comment: Have you tried actually accessing the names? It may simply be that they're hidden from `%whos`, even if they're really there.

Comment: @Thomas K:  You're right!  If you put this in an answer, I'll accept it.  So is this a bug in IPython?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reposting as an answer: the names are actually placed into your interactive namespace, but names defined when IPython starts are hidden from `%whos`, so it says that the namespace is empty, even though it's not. If you try using the names, they should work normally.